# Million ManyToMany Entries - Memory Problems

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, many-to-many, limit

i develope a type of "Statistics-Web".

For example i have some blog entries and for each visitor a extra statistic entry.

**Example blog entity:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Statistic", inversedBy="blogid")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="blog_statistics")
 */
private $statistics;
```

**Example statistic entity:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Blog", mappedBy="statistics")
 */
private $blog;
```

In the entity for statistic i have more fields like "time, user, ip".
In the Blog entity i have fields like "text, title, time".

At the beginning i had 1 Entry.
Everything is working / good.

A week later, i had 5.000 Entries (DB) for 2 Blog Entries. (2.500 per blog entry)
I get php memory problems.

I think doctrine tries to load all 2.500 Entries into the RAM/Cache.
But i only need the last one for the "last visited" information.
I could get the rest of the entries if i needed them. (statistics overview)

**Whats the best to "limit" entries?**
Current call: "Repository->fetchAll"

Comment: Sort and limit directly in your query, so only the rows you searching for being hydrated into php objects.

Comment: I have 2 entries ... Or you mean a Annotation like @ORM\Limit(1)

Comment: May you post more code, where you call your fetchAll and on which repo?

Comment: A "repository->fetchAll()" is all :D Imagine a list with all blog entries... "for blogentry in blogentries ... {{ blogentry.title }} ... endfor" No Specification ...

Comment: Please post the controller/template code with all the for loops. I think you are looping trough all 5k entries, that's the problem.

Comment: No. Imagine: $entries = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('TestBlogBundle:Blog')->findAll();
return array('entries' => $entries);

The problem is the many-to-many.
I think doctrine would load every many-to-many statistic. Because there to much, they get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved...**

Only use "fetch" option in many-to-many relation:

```
@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Statistic", inversedBy="blogid", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
```

Then you could use this function to get latest statistic entry:

```
public function getLatestStatistic()
{
    $cur = array();
    if(count($this->getStatistics()) > 0)
    {
        $cur = $this->getStatistics()->slice(count($this->getStatistics()) - 1, 1);
    }
    return count($cur) > 0 ? $cur[0] : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty obvious:

```
$lastStatisticsRecord = $repository->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->orderBy('s.time', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
```

This query would select only the last statistics entity from the table. 
If you need to get a blog entry with the last statistics entry, just make a JOIN statement:

```
 $lastStatisticsRecord = $repository->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->select(array('s', 'b'))
        ->leftJoin('s.blogid', 'b')
        ->orderBy('s.time', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
```

Comment: Ok. If i use your code, i must remove the "private $statistics;" from the entity. right?
Or doesnt load the QueryBuilder the ManyToMany Connections?
Then thats perfect :)

Comment: No, leave your relationship description as it is now, just use the queries i offered ;)